# Better way to manage connection strings in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, connection-string

I have multiple projects which connects to the same database through the connection-string, and they all have the same app.config data.

When, or if, I change my database I'm going to have to update all of these projects, and I will likely forget some which will make things very messy.

Is there a way to unify all these connection-strings to a single place to reduce complexity?

Comment: Normally the connection strings are placed in app.config files, so when/if your connection string changes I don't think that it would be much of a burden to do a simple string/replace in Visual Studio.

Comment: Would it be back practice to create a dll that has a static `SpecificConnClass` in it, then reference it in the projects? Then you change it in one place, rebuild and you're good.

Comment: Seems the flexibility of the configuration bothers you, then just hard-code it. When the code is going to be changed frequently, if a feature was annoying to you, don't use.

Comment: I guess it depends on the structure of your application. You could read it from one config file and give it to each of your _models_.

Comment: does your all application run on a single machine?

Answer (score 0):

if your all application run on a single machine then what you are looking for is

> [ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224437.aspx)

it is the way of using a single exe configuration among multiple exe.

Hope this help you out.